# How to change background-color of the respective paragraph by clicking on prepended paragraph number using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have 6 paragraphs as follows:

```
<div id="col2">

<p class="firstparagraph"> firstparagraph </p>
<p class="secondparagraph"> secondparagraph </p>
<p class="thirdparagraph">  thirdparagrap  </p>
<p class="fourthparagraph"> fourthparagraph </p>
<p class="fifthparagraph">  fifthparagraph  </p>
<p class="sixthparagraph">  sixthparagraph  </p>
</div>
```

Now I have a jQuery code to prepend paragraph numbers to these paragraphs as follows:

```
$("#buttonGparano").click(function(){
$("#col2 p").each(function(count){
        $(this).prepend(count+1);
    });
    $(this).off("click");
});
```

Now the requirement is to make a toggle master button clicking on which once:
- enables highlighting the respective paragraph on clicking of respective paragraph number.

Clicking again on the master button:
- disables highlighting the paragraphs on clicking of respective paragraph numbers.

I tried this code.

```
$("#buttonHhighlight").click(function(){
$("#col2 p").click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass("orig");
});
});
<style>
.orig
{
background-color:yellow;
}
</style>
```

If I click anywhere on the paragraph, it is working. I want it to work only if I click on the prepended paragraph no.

If anyone has some idea, please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I think that using a `<p>` to contain the counter of 'original' paragraphs is somewhat wrong, I'd suggest this approach as an option:

```
// iterate over the relevant <p> elements:
// using the before() method to insert
// new elements before the selected elements:
$('#col2 p').before(function(i) {

  // here we create a <p> element:
  return $('<p />', {
    // setting the text to the index of
    // the <p> element found in the
    // original collection:
    'text': i,

    // supplying a class-name to the
    // class attribute:
    'class' : 'count'
  });
// before() returns the original element
// before which the new content was inserted;
// here we use prev() to find the previous
// element (that we just inserted)
// and then use on() to bind a click
// event-handler:
}).prev().on('click', function() {

  // this finds the next() sibling element
  // and, in response to the clicks,
  // toggles the 'orig' class-name:
  $(this).next().toggleClass('orig');
});
```

```js
$('#col2 p').before(function(i) {
  return $('<p />', {
    'text': i,
    'class' : 'count'
  });
}).prev().on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('orig');
});
```

```css
.count {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.orig {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="col2">
  <p class="firstparagraph">firstparagraph</p>
  <p class="secondparagraph">secondparagraph</p>
  <p class="thirdparagraph">thirdparagrap</p>
  <p class="fourthparagraph">fourthparagraph</p>
  <p class="fifthparagraph">fifthparagraph</p>
  <p class="sixthparagraph">sixthparagraph</p>
</div>
```

As I mentioned, above, that I think using a `<p>` element is wrong &ndash a counter does not, really, constitute a paragraph – I'd suggest instead adding a child-element to the `<p>` elements, and use CSS to position it outside of that `<p>` element.

This maintains a relationship between the two elements and simplifies the event-binding:

```
// selecting the <p> elements,
// using the prepend() method to
// insert a new child-element at
// the beginning of the <p> elements:
$('#col2 p').prepend(function(i) {

  // creating a <span> element:
  return $('<span />', {
    // setting its text to the index
    // of the <p>:
    'text': i,

    // setting the class-name:
    'class': 'counter'

  // binding a click event-handler:
  }).on('click', function() {

    // on clicking the <span> the
    // closest ancestor <p> element has
    // the class-name of 'orig' toggled:
    $(this).closest('p').toggleClass('orig');
  });
});
```

```js
$('#col2 p').prepend(function(i) {
  return $('<span />', {
    'text': i,
    'class': 'counter'
  }).on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('p').toggleClass('orig');
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2em;
  min-height: 2em;
}
.counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  width: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.orig {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="col2">
  <p class="firstparagraph">firstparagraph</p>
  <p class="secondparagraph">secondparagraph</p>
  <p class="thirdparagraph">thirdparagrap</p>
  <p class="fourthparagraph">fourthparagraph</p>
  <p class="fifthparagraph">fifthparagraph</p>
  <p class="sixthparagraph">sixthparagraph</p>
</div>
```

Further, to address the requirement that the answer must provide the click functionality *only*, I'll offer this, which adapts your existing code:

```
$("#col2 p").each(function(count) {
  // here we wrap the prepended counter with
  // a <span> element, in order to distinguish
  // the counter from the rest of the <p>:
  $(this).prepend('<span class="counter">' + (count + 1) + '</span>')

    // finding the prepended <span> (because
    // prepend() returns the element to which it
    // was prepended):
    .find('span.counter')
    // binding the click event-handler:
    .on('click', function() {
      // toggling the 'orig' class on the
      // closest <p> ancestor:
      $(this).closest('p').toggleClass('orig');
  });
});
```

```js
$("#col2 p").each(function(count) {
  $(this).prepend('<span class="counter">' + (count + 1) + '</span>').find('span.counter').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('p').toggleClass('orig');
  });
});
```

```css
.counter {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.orig {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="col2">
  <p class="firstparagraph">firstparagraph</p>
  <p class="secondparagraph">secondparagraph</p>
  <p class="thirdparagraph">thirdparagrap</p>
  <p class="fourthparagraph">fourthparagraph</p>
  <p class="fifthparagraph">fifthparagraph</p>
  <p class="sixthparagraph">sixthparagraph</p>
</div>
```

References:

- [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: But I don't want the paragraph nos. They are already there. Just on clicking them, background color should change. Your code is also prepending the paragraph numbers.

Comment: You're welcome, though it seems the answer became less-useful to you? May I ask what, or how, it failed? And yes: I chose to do that because your approach was a little poor (in my opinion). However, while my code can be adapted to perform the task you require, it needs some way to identify the added, and the original, `<p>` elements. Which your own code doesn't suggest exists; if you add that means to distinguish elements then I can update this answer.

Comment: The problem is that I have separate button for prepending nos. and another separate button for allowing the css to change on clicking them. But your code does both in the single button.

Comment: Well, I've updated the answer to adapt your own code, which may more closely satisfy your needs.

Comment: Thanks again. I got a good idea on how to deal with such problems